# How to use variable wire data as an integer data for part select?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to control the width of `data` bus using part select.

But, the following error occurs:

> r_count is not a constant.

Is there a way in which I can use the wired `r_count` bit values as a constant decimal for defining the range of the vector being taken?

This is the part of the code:

```verilog
module shiftdata (data, r_count, out_data);

    input [32:0] data;

    input [4:0] r_count;

    output [20:0] out_data;

    assign out_data = data[r_count-1:r_count+5];

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your question what you are trying to acheive - you say in the comments that you are looking to select a variable width, but your code example (even if it compiled) would always be trying to access a 7-bit amount from `data`. In that case @Light's answer would be the way forward.

However based on the name of your module, and signal names, I'm going to hazard a guess that what you are actually trying to accomplish is a simple bit-shift, setting the `out_data` to a specific part of the `data` bus. In this case, you can simply use the bit-shift operator:

```
assign out_data = data >> r_count;
```

I've assumed right shift there (based on the name `r_count`), but you could equally use left shift (`<<`) or arithmetic right shift (`>>>` - sign extending shift for 2's complement).

You may get warnings about truncation, in which case you can either ignore the warning, or add an intermediate step:

```
wire [31:0] data_rshift;
assign data_rshift = data >> r_count;
assign out_data = data_rshift[20:0];
```

Comment: Yes I forsake part select and did this with shifting one time at the right and one time at the left depending on the variable width

Answer (score 1):

Use this format:

```
vect[base_expr +: width_expr]
```

or

```
vect[base_expr -: width_expr]
```

See "5.2.1 Vector bit-select and part-select addressing" in IEEE.1364-2005 LRM.

Comment: What if I want to have a variable length as in I want the length to be variable, instead of a constant?

Comment: This does not answer the question about variable signal width.

Comment: @TahmidMahbub170021040 in the example code you provide in the question, you are not changing the width of the selected signal - your code (if it were valid) would always result in a 7-bit wide slice at varying offset, in whichc ase this answer would do the same legally (`data[r_count-1+:7]`). If you want a variable width, you'd have to more accurately describe what you want with a matching example (even invalid). In any case, variable width is not possible (think about the hardware, a data bus couldn't suddenly become wider - where would the hardware come from).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with the Verilog code you are attempting to use.

As the error demonstrates, the code has a syntax error.  It is illegal in Verilog to use variable signals for vector part selects.  The *width* of the part-select must be a **constant**.

Even if that syntax were legal, you would have another problem because the part-select would have bits that are out of range.  For example, when `r_count`=0, (`r_count-1`)=-1, which is out of range of `data`, whose lower index is 0.

Another potential problem is that you might also be inferring unintended latches if you are not assigning to all 21 bits of `out_data`.

Since you can't use the compact syntax that you would like to use, you must find another approach.  For example, you could consider using a `case` statement with 32 case items (one for each of the 32 values of `r_count`).